# Has there been an NBA player who won triple MVP in one season?

Tags: basketball, history, nba, trivia, awards

Has there been an NBA player who won the all 3 NBA MVP awards?

this includes Regular Season MVP, Finals MVP and All-Star MVP award in the same season?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Only 3 players have accomplished winning all three NBA MVP awards in the same season:

1. **Michael Jordan** (twice) of the Chicago Bulls - ***1995-1996*** and ***1997-1998***
2. **Willis Reed** of the New York Knicks - ***1969-1970***
3. **Shaquille O'Neal** of the Los Angeles Lakers  - ***1999-2000***

Sources ([1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NBA_Most_Valuable_Player_Award)) ([2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bill_Russell_NBA_Finals_Most_Valuable_Player_Award)) ([3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NBA_All-Star_Game_Most_Valuable_Player_Award))

Answer (score 0):

1969-70
Willis Reed Jr., NYK Center:

- Finals Most Valuable Player
  PPG: 23, RPG: 10.5, APG: 2.8
- League Most Valuable Player
  PPG: 21.7, RPG: 13.9, APG: 2.0
- All Star Game Most Valuable Player
  21 Points 11 Rebounds

1995-96
Michael Jordan, CHI Shooting Guard:

- Finals Most Valuable Player
  PPG: 27.3, RPG: 5 3, APG: 4.2
  BLKPG: 0.2, STLPG: 1.7
- League Most Valuable Player
  PPG: 30.4, RPG: 6.6, APG: 4.3
  BLKPG: 0.5, STLPG: 2.2
- All Star Game Most Valuable Player
  20 Points 4 Rebounds 1 Assist 1 Steal

1999-2000
Shaquille O'Neal, LAL Center:

- Finals Most Valuable Player
  PPG: 38.0, RPG: 16.7, APG: 2.3
  BLKPG: 2.7, STLPG: 1.0
- League Most Valuable Player
  PPG: 29.7, RPG: 13.6, APG: 3.8
  BLKPG: 3.0, STLPG: 0.5
- All Star Game Most Valuable Player
  22 Points 9 Rebounds 3 Assists 3 Blocks

Answer (score -1):

The first Player to win the Big Three (All-Star, League, and Finals MVP) was Willis Reed of the NY Knicks in 1970. Michael was the second and Shaq was not the only one to win the All-Star MVP in 2000. He had to share it with Tim Duncan. 
[NBA All Star Game Most Valuable Player Award](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NBA_All-Star_Game_Most_Valuable_Player_Award)

Comment: Welcome to SE.Sport, can you please provide any sources to Willis Reed details?

Comment: Welcome. This is a rehash of the already [accepted answer](http://sports.stackexchange.com/a/1228). The only piece of added information provided here is that Shaq shared his MVP with Tim Duncan.

Comment: Exactly.  Which should have served as a comment rather than a distinct answer.